# Font awesome icons displayed as empty squares when font awesome is installed using NPM

Tags: npm, font-awesome-5

I have installed font awesome using npm command npm i -D @fortawesome/fontawesome-free.

Then I try to import it in my scss file in 2 ways.

@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all';
or
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';

after this I'm only getting blank squares instead of my icons. I'm using font awesome in my scss files like

```
.radioStyle input[type=radio] + label:before { 
content:"\f111"; 
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
color: $button-grey; 
font-size: 24px; 
padding-right: 8px; 
vertical-align:middle; }
```

also I'm using it in my html and I tried also to replace class fa with fas or fab

and none of these is working. When I use CDN everything is working as expected.

any advice?

Comment: May you post your html code, please?

Comment: sure, this is the part where font awesome is used <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>Comments</a>

Answer (score 1):

When this happens to me, it's because I forgot to load their JavaScript or put the font files somewhere that's accessible from the browser. Another common cause of this is the importing the font awesome core but not any styles such as solid.

**SCSS/Font Docs:**
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/sass#compile

**Example Import**

```
@import "variables";    
@import "/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
```

**JavaScript Docs:**
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers#next